# Where to put API key for Twitter Key for Android

Tags: android, twitter

I'm a little confused on where I need to place the API keys for the Twitter Kit for Android. Searching online mostly comes up with Fabric API, which i'm not using

According to the dev section on twitter, it says to put the key here:
(https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation)

```
 Next, add your API key and secret to your application resources.

 <resources>
   <string 
 android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
   <string 
 android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
 </resources>
```

Is this just going to be in the Strings.xml? It doesn't seem to like the android:name when it's in the string.xml file. It seems that Fabric API has their key put into the AndroidManifest file, as meta-data. This doesn't seem to be too clear on where it needs to be put. I'm assuming it's in the wrong area for me, as i can't get any tweets from the UserTimeLine to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this @onCreate of your target activity

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.CONSUMER_KEY), getString(R.string.CONSUMER_SECRET)))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
```

Answer (score 4):

I find the docs to be misleading as well. Maybe they will edit it in the future. Yes you can put it on `strings.xml`. You just have to omit the `android` prefix.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SampleTwitterClient</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">asdfasdf</string>
    <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">asdfasdf</string>
</resources>
```

Adding it on AndroidManifest.xml `meta-data` won't work. It's used by Fabric, not Twitter SDK.